# Can I change the way Maxima/wxMaxima displays the transpose operator?

Tags: maxima

Can I change the way Maxima displays the transpose operator? The (default) of just printing "transpose" uses very much space and makes the formulae harder to read.

When I enter:

```
transpose(M)
```

I would like it to print something like
**M<sup>T</sup>**.

I use Maxima through wxMaxima.

PS. There is no tag for wxMaxima on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great question. Unfortunately there isn't a way to handle it within Maxima itself, but if it's OK to do a little Lisp programming, we can solve it.

```
(%i1) :lisp (defun dimension-transpose (expr stuff) (dimension-superscript `((mexpt) ,(cadr expr) |$t|) stuff))
DIMENSION-TRANSPOSE
(%i1) :lisp (setf (get '%transpose 'dimension) 'dimension-transpose)
DIMENSION-TRANSPOSE
(%i1) transpose(A.B);
                                     T    T
(%o1)                               B  . A
```

Essentially we just define a display function which constructs an MEXPT (i.e. "^") expression and displays that, and then tell Maxima to use the new function to display `transpose` expressions.

Be careful to copy the punctuation exactly as it is shown. Be careful to distinguish backtick from single quote.

EDIT: The above works for command-line Maxima. For wxMaxima probably there is some similar procedure, but I don't know it.

Comment: Now I just have to find I way to fix it in wxMaxima too.